# Não está salvando no Banco de Dados

Tags: php, html

Estou aprendendo a programar em PHP, Analisem meus códigos e me ajudam a ver no que estou errando, pois não está salvando no Banco de Dados.

Página inicial a onde eu faço o Cadastro - Cadastro_clientes.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Cadastro de Clientes</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/style.css">
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div align="center" class="banner">
        <img src="img/Banner Giga.jpg">
         <form method="post" action="processa.php">
             <h1>Cadastro de Clientes</h1>
             <label>Nome:</label> <input type="text" class="campo" name="nome" required placeholder="Digite seu Nome:" maxlength="100"/><br><br>
             <label>Telefone:</label> <input type="text" class="campo" name="telefone" placeholder="Digite seu Telefone" maxlength="14"/><br><br>
             <label>Bairro:</label> <input type="text" class="campo" name="bairro" placeholder="Digite o seu Bairro" maxlength="100"/><br><br>
             <label>Rua:</label> <input type="text" class="campo" name="rua" placeholder="Digite sua Rua" maxlength="100"/><br><br>
             <label>Numero:</label> <input type="text" class="campo" name="numero_casa" placeholder="Numero da Casa" maxlength="100"/><br><br>
             <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Salvar"   class="btn btn-danger">
             <input type="reset"   value="Limpar"  class="btn btn-danger">
             </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Conexão com o Banco de Dados - Conexão.php

```
<?php
$hostname= "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "gigabyte";
$conexao = mysqli_connect($hostname,$user,$password,$database);
mysqli_select_db($conexao,$database);
if(!$conexao){
    echo "Falha na conexão com o Banco de Dados";

}
?>
```

Validações para salvar no banco de Dados - processa.php

```
<?php
include_once("conexao.php");
 $nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'nome');
 echo "Nome: $nome <br>";
 $telefone =filter_input(INPUT_POST,'telefone');
 echo  "Telefone: $telefone<br>";
 $bairro =filter_input(INPUT_POST,'bairro' );
 echo  "Bairro: $bairro<br>";
 $rua =filter_input(INPUT_POST,'rua' );
 echo  "Rua: $rua<br>";
 $numero =filter_input(INPUT_POST,'numero_casa');
 echo  "Numero: $numero<br>";
$result="INSERT INTO clientes (nome,telefone,bairro,rua,numero_casa) VALUES('',$nome', '$telefone', '$bairro', '$rua', '$numero'))";
$resultado= mysqli_query($conexao, $result);
if($result == true){
    echo "Cadastrado com Sucesso!";
}else{
    echo "Opa, Algo de errado não está certo";
}


?>
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow **em português**. Faça o [tour] para saber como funciona a **comunidade**, também acesse a [help] para fazer bom uso do site.

Comment: Esta retornando erro? No arquivo **processa.php** na variável `$result` tem sobrando um **parênteses** `... '$numero'))";`

Comment: Além de estar sobrando o parênteses, esse `''` antes de `$nome` no `VALUES` está sobrando: `$result="INSERT INTO clientes (nome,telefone,bairro,rua,numero_casa) VALUES('',$nome', '$telefone', '$bairro', '$rua', '$numero'))";`

Comment: Ainda não está funcionando :(

Comment: Não está retornando erro nenhum, porém quando vou inserir os dados no meu HTML e clico em salvar e vou olhar no Banco de Dados, não tem nada salvo lá.

Comment: Você está usando qual servidor web? Apache? Procure no arquivo de log para ver qual o erro que está acontecendo.

Answer (score 0):

Faça o seguinte

```
<?php

include_once("conexao.php");
$nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'nome');
echo "Nome: $nome <br>";
$telefone =filter_input(INPUT_POST,'telefone');
echo  "Telefone: $telefone<br>";
$bairro =filter_input(INPUT_POST,'bairro' );
echo  "Bairro: $bairro<br>";
$rua =filter_input(INPUT_POST,'rua' );
echo  "Rua: $rua<br>";
$numero =filter_input(INPUT_POST,'numero_casa');
echo  "Numero: $numero<br>";
$result="INSERT INTO clientes (nome,telefone,bairro,rua,numero_casa) VALUES('$nome', '$telefone', '$bairro', '$rua', '$numero')";
$resultado= mysqli_query($conexao, $result);
if($result == true){
    echo "Cadastrado com Sucesso!";
}else{
    echo "Opa, Algo de errado não está certo";
}


?>
```